# What database for Data Acquisition?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I have to develop a database that will be used for data acquisition, mainly measurements from micrometer which will be compared against a Reference Table inside the db. The platform is OS X. I have been looking at Valentina-DB, SQLite and even MySQL.

My main requirement is: The database will be used by factory workers which may not have a lot of experience in using software. Therefore, the front-end has to be extremely easy to use. This includes installation of the database and the front-end.

What are my options when it comes to custom GUI apps?

Answer (score 0):

Most of databases have no GUI front-end to use "by factory workers for data acquisition" so you need to program it yourself.

One of the approaches would be to use Java Swing GUI and some Java-based database like Apache Derby maybe. You could put everything into runnable jars, talk to database exclusively [directly](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html) (not network setup, no authentication) and Java is available on OS X form Oracle website. Seems relatively easy to setup and would also run under Windows if at the end desired. This is not the only possible approach but something that is likely to work.

There are many possible alternative approaches.